# Including the month where I only worked the first day on my resume

Tags: job-change, philippines

I originally ended my employment with a company in the Philippines on June 30<sup>th</sup> which is what my resignation letter says, but my employer asked me to extend that by a day, making July 1<sup>st</sup> my last day.

**Can I now list this job on my resume as "*May 20XX - July 2016*"?**

**What will my [Certificate of Employment](http://www.dole.gov.ph/news/view/2986) (COE) say?**

Comment: you mean Job history as your resume/cv? Then yes you could.

Comment: Yes. Quite tricky because of the Certificate of Employment might state July 1 only.

Comment: So? as long as you dont set 25 July nobody should care. Your end date was in July so put up July if you want to.

Comment: "Can I treat that extension to become start date from them" - don't you mean end date? For example, you might say that you worked at the company from ???? 2014 up to and including 1 Jul 2016. But for a CV I think it is common to just write dates down to the month, e.g. Jan 2014 - Jun 2016. The end month means that you worked the whole month.

Comment: So is your question: "*My final day is July 1st, can I list this job on my resume as 'May 20XX - July 2016'?*" ?

Comment: Which country?  On a resume for the US, it's not that important.  For other documents in other countries, it might matter.

Comment: Yes, since July is the last month you will have worked for them.  Nobody in the world with any common sense would bust you for that one.  Consequently, if anyone ***does*** give you a hard time, you don't want to work there anyway.

Comment: @Brandin: End date.

Comment: @Lilienthal: Yup.

Comment: @Dan: I am in the Philippines, and there are some kind of requirements like Cert. Of Employment, which I am worried about.

Comment: @Richard: Mhm, that could make sense for this one.

Comment: @Ju-chan Is it then accurate to say that the second part of your question would be "*What will my Certificate of Employment say?*"

Comment: @Lilienthal Mhm, exactly! And what would be the impact of the said certificate to employer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you *could* do this, the real question is whether or not you *should* do this.

Your resume is a statement of your qualifications, experience, and communication abilities.

If I read on a resume that you worked from May XX - July 2016, the assumption I will make is that you worked all, or a significant portion, of your final month.

**This boosts your experience by a month. It is misleading.**

Now, if you've worked at your previous job for several years, it probably doesn't make a big difference in your perceived level of experience. Small, but still misleading.

But if this is a short contract, say from May 2016 - June 2016, then you would be implying that you worked for 3 months instead of 2, boosting your perceived experience by 50%. Very misleading.

So, if I choose to interview you or hire you based on your resume and the truth comes out it will change how I see you as a candidate - I will see you as someone willing to mislead me for your own benefit.

**I will not care that it is technically true; I will not trust you.**

The alternative, is that you list May XX - June 2016 on your resume. You are now under-reporting your own experience by a day.

Will this make you look less qualified? No.

Will it effect my perception of you if I find out the truth? 
**Yes --> This is where you can truly convince me that you are someone worth hiring.**

"So Ju-chan, you worked for company XYZ until June 2016?"

"Well, technically I worked for them until July 1st, they needed me to stay longer than my intended end date, and I really enjoyed working for them so I was happy to stay a little longer to help out" *<-- this is you showing me a great example of your character as an employee.*

So, you decide for yourself whether or not it's worth it.

Comment: This makes sense from an employer's standpoint. Thank you :D

Answer (score 2):

As July 1st is your last day at the company, you can absolutely say you were at the company until July on your resume.

As for your Certificate of Employment, it is probably best to contact the appropriate government office or a lawyer that has experience with those documents.